# Почему в консоль вылетает VK is not defined или Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vkontakte-api, github-pages, openapi

Всем доброй ночи.
Использую Open Api для работы с vk api. Подключаю асинхронно. На локалке все работает прекрасно. Задеплоила на gh-pages - выдало ошибку при попытке подгрузить пользователей.
[image: ошибка 1]
[image: ошибка 1]

Поддержка вк сказала, что:
"Эта ошибка может означать, что на момент вызова скрипт openapi.js еще не загрузился. Вам нужно найти способ исправить это. Вызывайте функции, связанные с VK, только после того, как openapi.js будет загружен."

Подключила синхронно, как опять же указано в документации vk api, в той ее части, что связана с Open API.
Получила другую ошибку:
[image: ошибка 2]
[image: ошибка 2]

И в отличие от предыдущей, я ее получаю не только на gh-pages, но и на локалке.
На что поддержка вк вежливо сказала, что вопросами Open API она не занимается.

Собственно, обращаюсь сюда: может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? У меня 0 идей, что эта адская машина от меня хочет.

Comment: Привет! Нужен пример кода, который у вас вызывается на локалке. Лучше не скриншотом, а как вставка кода. По ошибке - при вызове функции, один из параметров равен null. И тут надо понять, откуда этот параметр приходит и как объявляется